# Notificação de reputação mínima em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Fui deixar um comentário numa pergunta e recebi a notificação de que não tenho a pontuação mínima necessária, mas ela está em inglês:

[image: Notificação em inglês]

Comment: Verdade eu também recebi a mesma coisa quando hoje a tarde não tinha ainda 50. Bem observado...